# Display picture from AppEngine BlobStore at HTML

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to display pictures from AppEngine BlobStore at HTML page. Because AppEngine does not expose FileSystem, i can't write:

```
[img src="pic.jpg"/]
```

May be it is possible to directly access blob-bytes and display it like:

```
[img src="..base64 data..."/]
```

But this is very ugly way. I always thought that it is enough to use upload URL provided by AppEngine:

```
[img src="/serve?blob-key=AMIfv95txVuc" /]
```

but this does not work for me [pic is not displayed]. What all i need to do to display pic, did i forgot something? thx

Comment: Go through [this](http://ikaisays.com/2010/09/08/gwt-blobstore-the-new-high-performance-image-serving-api-and-cute-dogs-on-office-chairs/) tutorial. I get the feeling you might have misunderstood how the blobstore works :)

Comment: You should probably explain *how* it doesn't work.  Do you get an error?  Do you have a handler defined to serve the image at /serve?  You might also want to check out [get_serving_url](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html#Image_get_serving_url).

Comment: I wrongly expected "magic" google function blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res) to do all the work. Thanks to Marvin for link to tutorial on google image service. I'd recomend to follow image service docs instead of { http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/ } which i did only. Image service have exactly what i needed: function  String getServingUrl(BlobKey blobKey). Thx again